# How to use IdentityRoleClaim Table (IdentityRoleClaim<TKey> Class) in Identity in ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity, claims-based-identity

I am trying to make the best use of [Identity Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio). In Identity, I am seeing, there are 7 tables like this-

[image: Identity Tables]

In there, I am curious about this table-

[image: RoleClaim Table]

Which can be found in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.identityroleclaim-1?view=aspnetcore-1.1).

I am trying to use this table for claim based authentication where Super Admin can assign claims onto any role. So that Roles could be dynamic. So, what I am thinking is something like this-

[image: ERD]

But there is no table exists named **`Claim`** or close to this.

That is why I am thinking I have some gap in my knowledge. But there is no clear documentation known to me on this topic as far as I have found.

Can anyone please let me know,

1. How can I add an entry to the **RoleClaim** table?
2. Why there is no **Claim** table in ***Identity***?
3. Is there any clear documentation regarding this?

I have found one close to my need, but I am not sure. The doc can be found in **[here](https://benfoster.io/blog/asp-net-identity-role-claims/)** and **[here](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2019/10/29/aspnet-authentication.aspx)**.
Thanks in advance for helping.

### Re-

If needed, my total code can be found in **[here](https://github.com/AbrarJahin/Asp.NetCore_3.1-PostGRE_StartupProject)**.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.How can I add an entry to the RoleClaim table?

```
var accountRole = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync("Admin");

await _roleManager.AddClaimAsync(accountRole, new Claim("Manage", "Cashier"));
```

Reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53332171/11398810

> 2.Why there is no Claim table in Identity?

This is by design.I think you need to raise question in github to ask for PG for help.

Reference:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues

> 3.Is there any clear documentation regarding this?

There seems to be no official document to explain them.