# .Net Core 3 AuthorizationFilter for Each IActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-identity

From my research, I know (believe) I need an `AuthorizationFilter`, but I'm not clear on actual implementation.

In my .Net Core 3.1 MVC app, I've created users and roles. I've added the ability for a `User` or a `Role` to have `Claims`. I built a `ManageClaims` (one for users and one for roles) view which lists each controller and their `IActionResult`'s as a `Claim`.

I get the list like this:

```
var controllers = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                    .Where(type => typeof(Controller).IsAssignableFrom(type))
                    .SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public))
                    .Where(m => !m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute), true).Any())
                    .Select(x => new { Type = x.DeclaringType.Name, Value = x.Name })
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Type).ThenBy(x => x.Value)
                    .Distinct()
                    .ToList();
```

`Claims` look like this:

```
Claim Type              Claim Value
-----------------------------------
HomeController          Index
HomeController          Privacy
HomeController          Error
UsersController         Index
UsersController         Create
UsersController         Details
UsersController         Edit
UsersController         Delete
...
```

What I'm trying to do is add a simple `Attribute` to either the `Controller` or each `IActionResult` (depending on my needs for a specific controller) to check if the user has a claim to that controller's method. Similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50719054/286618 however I don't want to provide any parameters. Instead I want the authorization to figure out what's being access and then figure out if they have a claim to it.

This allows me to grant/remove access to a controller's method on the fly for a user or role without having to hard code any policy's etc.

Any feedback on this methodology is welcome as well.

Thank you.

Comment: maybe you can set user role in Session and in Attribute get user role from Session and validate it without any parametr in controller